# Unusual password protect software

Tags: passwords

Is there software that will do this:

- Create a folder and name it.
- Password protect that folder.
- Folder is empty.
- Now drop a file to be password protected into that folder without having to go through the trouble of password protecting it, i.e. it is automatically password protected.
- Other files to be added in the same way.

To retrieve a file either:

1. password unprotect the folder and choose the file, or,
2. open up the folder, choose a file and unprotect that.

Answer (score 1):

This post probably needs to be moved to [SE Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but I'm not a mod here.

At any rate, (assuming your OS of choice is Windows) the functionality you're looking for can be realized with a BitLocker encrypted external drive or flash drive, via "[BitLocker to go](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-to-go-faq)."

Answer (score 0):

Closest off the shelf offering would probably be veracrypt

https://www.veracrypt.fr/

If you wanted that precise functionality, you would likely need to build it.